# Chocolate Pieces

Tags: arithmetic

With only two linear cuts,
it is possible to divide the
chocolate cue represented
as a matrix of rows 4 and columns 5 so that
Aldo gets half,
Bruno a fifth, to Ciro the
remaining part.

> How much does Ciro get as a fraction?

> Answer this last
> question in two ways: either by deducting it from the figure
> based on the cuts made, or by calculating an
> an appropriate numerical expression.

---

The chocolate cue is represented as a matrix of 4 rows and 5 columns:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} X & X & X & X & X \\ X & X & X & X & X \\ X & X & X & X & X \\ X & X & X & X & X \end{bmatrix} $$
We cut the chocolate stick in half along the lines:

$$\begin{bmatrix} X & X & X & X & X \\ X & X & X & X & X \end{bmatrix} $$

$$\begin{bmatrix} X & X & X & X & X \\ X & X & X & X & X \end{bmatrix} $$
Aldo gets the upper half.

We cut the bottom half in half along the columns:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} X & X \\ X & X \end{bmatrix} $$

Aldo gets the top half, Bruno gets the piece on the left, and Ciro gets the piece on the right.

If we denote the total number of chocolate squares as $N$, we have:

1. Aldo gets $\frac{1}{2}N$.
2. Bruno gets $\frac{1}{5} \times \frac{1}{2}N = \frac{1}{10}N $.
3. Ciro gets $\frac{4}{5} \times \frac{1}{2}N = \frac{2}{5}N $.

The sum of these quantities must equal the total, so:

$$ \frac{1}{2}N + \frac{1}{10}N + \frac{2}{5}N = N $$

$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{10} + \frac{2}{5} = 1 $$

Cyrus gets $\frac{2}{5}$ of the chocolate stick but the solution is $3/10$.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity the question is likely to correct where he went wrong.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity How much does Ciro get as a fraction?

Comment: Why is there the request of closure? I have given the problem and my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bruno gets a fifth of the entire chocolate bar, not a fifth of the remaining half after Aldo gets his half. So Aldo gets $N/2$, Bruno gets $N/5$ and Ciro the rest. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Bruno gets $N/5$.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, thanks